# Update label when UITableViewCell is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view with many table view cells. When the user clicks on a cell, I want to update the cell's label text.

Here is my table view controller class:

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var data = [Data]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        // Here I fetch and populate the data list
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "MyTableViewCell"

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? MyTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of MyTableViewCell.")
        }

        let cellData = data[indexPath.row]

        cell.initialize(data: cellData)

        return cell
    }
}
```

And here is my table view cell class:

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var data: Data?

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    func initialize(data: Data) {
        self.data = data

        if let cellName = data.name {
            nameLabel.text = cellName
        }
    }
}
```

How can I change the text of the `nameLabel` above (to "Clicked") when the user clicks on the table view cell?

Answer (score 1):

There're no doubt different ways you could handle this, but here is what I would suggest:

Implement the UITableViewDelegate methods `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` and `tableView(_:didDeselectRowAt:)`. Add a `selected` bool to the data model for the cells in your table view, and update the state of that bool as the cells are selected/deselected.

Then modify your `cellForRow(at:)` method so it uses the `selected` flag to decide what to show in your label.

Finally, have your `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` and `tableView(_:didDeselectRowAt:)` methods tell the table view to reload the newly selected/deselected cell.

Comment: I'm able to select the row and have it change the label, but `didDeselectRowAt` never gets triggered.

Comment: I should also say that I want the user to be able to select many table view cells and that each of them should be able to have their label's change text back and forth when the user selects/deselects them.

Comment: It's been a while since I've dealt with tracking multiple selections in a table view. I seem to remember that you have to set up the table view correctly before it calls those methods to select/deselect the cells. Is a cell un-highlighting when it's selected and you tap it again?